# When we upgrade from GCMRegistrar to FirebaseMessaging, do we need to do any server side changes?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

We are planning on upgrading from GCMRegistrar to FirebaseMessaging and I need to verify that we do not need to do any changes to our server side implementation.

On the bottom of this page
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm
one can read that there should not be any changes required.

But two questions:

1. When we enable Firebase messaging, will the Authorization:key and
   the "sender id" be the same as the ones that we had in the Google
   API console for GCM?
2. Is there anything else we must consider on server side?

Many thanks
Ola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement from [GCM and FCM Frequently Asked Questions](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq) may alleviate your concerns:

> How is FCM server implementation different from GCM server
>   implementation?
>
> You won’t need to make any server-side protocol changes for the
>   upgrade. The service protocol has not changed. However, note that all
>   new server enhancements will be documented in [FCM server
>   documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server).